# how can i improve the speed up of my web page?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, gatsby, browser-cache, algolia

My website is very slow, every time i reload the page it takes about 8 to 9 seconds to render everything again, i wonder if there is any library to speed up the rendering again, i am using gatsby, reactjs.

I have configured gatsby by default, I should include something in gatsby config?

I have a section where a lot of images are displayed, the images are being stored in algolia, so I don't think they influence the timing

should I use some algolia library for the cache so it doesn't render slow?

Answer (score 1):

There are some things you can speed up your page and improve customer/user experience.

-**You should check that your react app does not have unnecessary renders**: put some console logs, see how many times your pages fire log and change your code so there are no unnecessary renders.
-**Cache images and assets that are shown in your page**: they will be loaded in first page visit (or when cache is removed) but next loads will be significantly faster (it can be x10 faster on non-initial load)
-**Use code splitting**:
Here is quotation how it works:

> Bundling is great, but as your app grows, your bundle will grow too.
> Especially if you are including large third-party libraries. You need
> to keep an eye on the code you are including in your bundle so that
> you don’t accidentally make it so large that your app takes a long
> time to load.
>
> To avoid winding up with a large bundle, it’s good to get ahead of the
> problem and start “splitting” your bundle. Code-Splitting is a feature
> supported by bundlers like Webpack, Rollup and Browserify (via
> factor-bundle) which can create multiple bundles that can be
> dynamically loaded at runtime.
>
> Code-splitting your app can help you “lazy-load” just the things that
> are currently needed by the user, which can dramatically improve the
> performance of your app. While you haven’t reduced the overall amount
> of code in your app, you’ve avoided loading code that the user may
> never need, and reduced the amount of code needed during the initial
> load.

Reference and example usage (example is actually react-native app, but it points out the advantages of code-splitting and lazy-loading):
https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html
https://sportsbet.tech/react-native-app-launch-improvements-30995f2585

Try these things. Cheers!

Comment: how can i use the cache to save the images? i should do something with gatsby? what library can i use ?

Comment: @brucelee I don't have much experience with react caching as I'm using myself react-native. So I cannot guide you to any library as I haven't tested them. But I would look how to cache with react and with gatsby. Good luck on finding solution that fits your use case :)